# LaTeX - Colouring the RandomWalk?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi I am using the randomwalk package in LaTeX alongside tikz in order to create a random design of lines. Is there a way I can manipulate other aspects of the lines drawn such as the colour or the width? Also I would like to know if there was a way to constrain the random walk to within a rectangle node created using the tikz package. I currently have this:

```
\node[anchor=center](randdes) at (box){%
        \RandomWalk {number=100, angles = {0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300}, degrees}
```

So the random walk is correctly centered within the box but it doesnt fill the entire width of the box. I'd actually like to have it fill from edge to edge.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fit the node exactly to the content you can set `inner sep=0`.
To change the color of the drawing, you can change the `every picture` style.
Here is an example :

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=7mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{randomwalk}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[anchor=center,draw=blue,inner sep=0,every picture/.style={draw=red, thick}](randdes)
      {\RandomWalk {number=100, angles = {0, 60, 120, 180, 240, 300}, degrees}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]